# List tests but don't run them

Tags: unit-testing, go

How do I list the tests available to `go test` without running them? I want to know what tests (including subtests) are present so I can manually pick a subset of them to run with a later command. I would expect something like `go test -l` or `go test -n` for something like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, you can't. But there is `grep` which works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go1.9 the `go test` command accepts a new `-list` flag, which takes a regular expression as an argument and prints to stdout the name of any tests, benchmarks, or examples that match it, without running them.

The [test flags documentation](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) can be found under https://tip.golang.org until the official go1.9 release.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `go` subcommand for that, but you can do it with a little bit of `find` and `grep` (GNU version, for the `-P` flag) magic:

```
find /path/to/your/project -not -path "./vendor" -type f -name "*_test.go" -exec cat {} \; | grep -oP '^func (\w+)\(\w \*testing\.T\) {$' | grep -oP ' \w+' | grep -oP '\w+';
```

Comment: _Assuming they're using Linux._

Comment: Also note this will list test functions but not subtests run with `T.Run`.

Comment: @Adrian it will also work on Mac if they install GNU grep.

Comment: It'll work on Windows if they install GNUWin32 grep & find also, but I imagine most people haven't.